# Loop through a variable and sum its components

Tags: batch-file

I just started learning batch and it's causing me a lot of trouble. What I want to do is to first enter 3 different variables and then make them into one variable. I then want to loop through that variable to sum all of its numbers.

Here's an example:

> Variable1: 123
>
> Variable2: 456
>
> Variable3: 789
>
> 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9 = 45

This is the code I have so far:

```
@echo off
SET /p var1="Enter var 1"
SET /p var2="Enter var 2"
SET /p var3="Enter var 3"
SET allvars=%var1%%var2%%var3%
set sum = 0
FOR %i IN (%allvars%) DO command [ %sum% = %sum% + %i% ]
echo %sum%
```

I've never written a FOR loop in batch before so I'm guessing I made a huge mistake with the synax. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better example:

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
SET /p "var1=Enter var 1 "
SET /p "var2=Enter var 2 "
SET /p "var3=Enter var 3 "
SET "allvars=%var1%%var2%%var3%"
for /f "delims=:" %%i in ('"(@echo(%allvars%&@echo()|findstr /o $"') do set /a len=%%i-4
set /a sum=0
FOR /l %%i IN (0,1,%len%) DO call set /a sum+=%%allvars:~%%i,1%%
echo %sum%
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! I don't want to be too needy, but is there any way you could explain both for loops? I have no idea what's going on with these both loops.

Comment: @Matthew the first loop uses `findstr /o` ([findstr syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)) to measure the length of `%allvars%`. The second loop uses the string conversion functions to get a substring of one char for the addition ([syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)).